# How to do I change the color of the labels and ticks of the color bar of a geopandas map in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been try to make a heatmap using geopandas, and I am successfully able to do so but I am not able to change the color of the ticks and label in the color map.. I also want to move the title to the center and add some padding to it...

this is the full code I used to generate the heatmap:

```py
from py_spoo_url import Statistics
import geopandas as gpd
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from typing import Literal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


stats = Statistics("https://spoo.me/ga")


def make_countries_heatmap(data, cmap: Literal["YlOrRd", "viridis", "plasma", "inferno"] = "RdPu_r"):
        world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

        world = world.merge(
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Country', 'Value']),
            how='left',
            left_on='name',
            right_on='Country'
        )

        plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10), dpi=100)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95)

        # Create a figure and axis
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 10))

        for spine in ax.spines.values():
            spine.set_color('white')

        ax.tick_params(labelcolor='white')

        # Plot the world map
        world.boundary.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1)
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)

        # Plot the heatmap
        world.plot(column='Value', ax=ax, legend=True, cax=cax, cmap=cmap, legend_kwds={'label': "Clicks"}, edgecolor=None, missing_kwds={'color': 'white'})

        # Set plot title
        plt.title('Countries Heatmap', loc='left', fontsize=20, fontweight=3, color='white')

        # Show the plot
        return plt


plt = make_countries_heatmap(data=stats.country_analysis, cmap="RdPu_r") # this returns a matplotlib.pyplot object
plt.savefig("heatmap.png", format="png", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1, dpi=300, transparent=True)
```

I tried doing this but it didnot work:

```py
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('Clicks', color='white')
cb.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color='white')
```

it gave this error:

```py
cb = plt.colorbar()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\desktop\testings\spooBot\env\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2322, in colorbar
    raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).
```

[Image showing the incorrect color and position of title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBVAx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Plot the world map and store the mappable

```
world_plot = world.plot(column='Value', ax=ax, legend=True, cmap=cmap, legend_kwds={'label': "Clicks"}, edgecolor=None, missing_kwds={'color': 'white'})
```

Then try plotting colorbar using the stored mappable

```
cb = plt.colorbar(world_plot, cax=cax)
```